# Unable to receive IOS notifications from Firebase Console

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am stuck on pushing notifications to users. In Xcode, I receive any and all notifications sent from Firebase. However, when pushed to the App Store, I no longer receive them.

It says on firebase that X amount are sent but zero received/open.

Here is my app delegate:

```
    Did Finish Launching:

    //Firebase Integration
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)

    //Enabling push notifications
    registerForPushNotifications()

    //Handle Notification
           
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: { _, _ in }
      )
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

Here is the general app delegate with its contents.

```
  General App Delegate:

    //Register for Push Not.
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      .requestAuthorization(
        options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, _ in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
        guard granted else { return }
        self?.getNotificationSettings()
      }
}
        //Get Settings
        func getNotificationSettings() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
    print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
    
    guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
  }
} 

    //Get the token
    func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
) {
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

Here are some extension functions. Not sure I need them.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func userNotificationCenter(
_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
willPresent notification: UNNotification,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
@escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
 ) {
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    completionHandler([[.banner, .sound]])
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
}

 func userNotificationCenter(
_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
 ) {
  completionHandler()
 }
}



 extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
 func messaging(
_ messaging: Messaging,
didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?
 ) {
let tokenDict = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
NotificationCenter.default.post(
  name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
  object: nil,
  userInfo: tokenDict)
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to firebase->Project Settings->Cloud Messaging -> then scroll down to Apple app configuration and make sure you've provided APNs Production Certificate or not, if not then generate production certificate and upload it there. Alternatively i suggest you to upload APNs Authentication Key instead of certificates.

[image: Preview Image]

Comment: What changed? This option is not available to me

Comment: Just to add to this, if you generate a new key: SAVE it somewhere. Apple does not allow you to download it again in the future. Also, Apple only allows you to make 1 key, so it is shared for all of your apps - adding a new app means using the same key (or replacing the key or all your apps if you have lost it).

Comment: Worked for me, you get to see your keys on `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` on developer apple page:
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list